# Connections to SSL ports using NIO stay established after disconnect

Tags: java, ssl, connection, nio

In our application we need to check if certain ports of certain host are available for communication. At stage of this check we do not proceed with real communication - we need just to check if ports are open. As many ports has to be checked at once we originally used NIO approach (Selector + SocketChannel classes):

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class TestNIO {

    public static void main(final String... params) {
        final List<String> portsToCheck = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"443", "5989"});
        final List<String> openPorts = new ArrayList<String>();
        final String host = "<SOME_IP>";
        final int timeout = 5000;

        Selector selector = null;
        if (!portsToCheck.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                selector = Selector.open();

                for (final String port : portsToCheck) {
                    final SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
                    channel.configureBlocking(false);
                    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.valueOf(port)));
                    channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                }

                final int readyChannels = selector.select(timeout);
                if (readyChannels != 0) {
                    final Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        final SelectionKey selKey = it.next();

                        try {
                            if (selKey.isValid() && selKey.isConnectable()) {
                                final SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) selKey.channel();
                                try {
                                    if (channel.finishConnect()) {
                                      openPorts.add(String.valueOf(channel.socket().getPort()));
                                    }
                                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                } finally {
                                    channel.close();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (final Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            selKey.cancel();
                        }
                        it.remove();
                    }
                }
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (selector != null && selector.isOpen()) {
                        selector.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.print("Open ports: " + openPorts.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach worked successfully for years at let's say hundreds of customers till at one of our customer this approach leaded to a problem. Namely, connections from client (where this check is running, it's Windows Server 2012 R2) to server (it's ESXi) at just one of SSL-ports stay established and never closed till restart of the server. This happens just with one of SSL-ports (standard 443), for example with another SSL-port - 5989 (it's HTTPS CIM server) this does not happen. Looks like this is because of some configuration on Windows side: 1. Happens just with one of several HTTPS ports; 2. Happens with any ESXi servers connected to this Windows client; 3. Does not happen with another Windows client connected to the same ESXi servers. Problem is that customer does not wish very much to cooperate with us finding the root cause and we have to guess it ourselves. We used another classic approach to check SSL-ports which works fine even in this problematic system. Here it is:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class TestHttpUrlConnection {

    public static void main(final String... params) {
        final List<String> portsToCheck = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"443", "5989"});
        final List<String> openPorts = new ArrayList<String>();
        final String host = "<SOME_IP>";
        final int timeout = 5000;

        if (!portsToCheck.isEmpty()) {
            trustAllHttpsCertificates();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            for (final String port : portsToCheck) {
                HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
                OutputStreamWriter out = null;
                try {
                    connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(
                        "https://" + host + ":" + Integer.valueOf(port)).openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                    final OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                    out = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF8");
                    out.close();
                    openPorts.add(port);
                } catch(final IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                        } catch (final IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Open ports: " + openPorts.toString());
        }
    }

    private static void trustAllHttpsCertificates() {
        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[1]; 
            trustAllCerts[0] = new TrustAllManager();
            final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null); 
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class TrustAllManager implements X509TrustManager {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return null; 
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] certs, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // Empty
        } 
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // Empty
        }
    }
}
```

But customer wants us to tell him the reason why one approach works and another does not. Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**
I've found out that on that problematic system even following code leads to a situation that each connection stays ESTABLISHED and not released back to system. This is not NIO and explicit `close()` on socket invoked:

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
SocketAddress serverSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
try {
    sock.connect(serverSocketAddress, timeout);
    if (sock.isConnected()) {
        openPorts.add(port);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (sock != null) {
        try {
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Setting `keepAlive` to `false` does not change the situation.

**UPDATE 2**

Problem repeated also on nonSSL-port (135, it's Hyper-V virtualization). And what confuses me most is that after restart of guest OS with which connections were established and and after stopping software which opened these connections, they are still marked as established on client machine. I consider there is really something wrong with the system itself (and has nothing to do with our Java code), but what exactly is wrong...

**UPDATE 3**
The problem was caused by TrendMicro's Anti-Virus software "Virus Buster". It prevented connections to be closed normally.

Comment: I question the entire problem. You don't need to check whether ports, or indeed any resource, are available until you need to use them; and the best way to check is to *try* to use them. Anything else amounts to predicting the future. It can't be done. Either it is available at the instant you need it or it isn't, and trying to use it will tell you whether it was there or not. Guesswork techniques like this can deliver both false positives and false negatives, due to the time difference between test and use. Don't try to use computers for fortune telling. It's not what they're for.

Comment: In common case your remark is true, but not in our specific case. We need to quickly determine which virtualization is working on server. Ans as different virtualizations uses different ports we check ports availability. Approaches I listed above satisfy all our requirements. Approach of sequential tries of full-fledged communication with each type of virtualization is too resource and time consumptive, and it does not meet requirements, we can not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Registered channels aren't completely closed until the next `select()` call. This is documented somewhere which I can never find when I look for it.

NB your trustAllCertificates() method does nothing useful except implement a radical insecurity, and calling it once per open socket that shouldn't be open at all appears to be completely pointless.

Comment: Do you mean that after call of `channel.finishConnect()` and `channel.close()` we have to call `selector.select()` once more? This is at least very strange, as `close()` method for channel and `cancel()` method for selection key would be invoked at that moment. Concerning `trustAllHttpsCertificates()` - it was added just for example/testing purpose, and you can't skip it even not proceeding with real communication, otherwise security exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @ŹmicierJurcevič That's not only what I meant, it's what I said. I don't understand your second sentence, but your `trustAllHttpsCertificates()` code remains insecure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by TrendMicro's Anti-Virus software "Virus Buster". It prevented connections to be closed normally.